# Get the name of dropped item into new div in jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jstree

I am creating a webs application like [easyquerybuilder](http://demo.easyquerybuilder.com/asp-net-mvc/) using `jstree.`
i am able to drag and drop `submenu items`. i want to get the name of the dropped item to new `div` . this is my  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nisham/LcmQ6/5/)

**this is my drag and drop code**

```
$('.drag').on('mousedown', function (e) {
    return $.vakata.dnd.start(e, { 'jstree' : true, 'obj' : $(this), 'nodes' : [{ id : true, text: $(this).text() }] }, '<div id="jstree-dnd" class="jstree-default"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-er"></i>' + $(this).text() + '</div>');
});

$(document).on('dnd_move.vakata', function (e, data) {
    var t = $(data.event.target);
    if(!t.closest('.jstree').length) {
        if(t.closest('.drop').length) {
            data.helper.find('.jstree-icon').removeClass('jstree-er').addClass('jstree-ok');
        }
        else {
            data.helper.find('.jstree-icon').removeClass('jstree-ok').addClass('jstree-er');
        }
    }
}).on('dnd_stop.vakata', function (e, data) {
    var t = $(data.event.target);
    if(!t.closest('.jstree').length) {
        if(t.closest('.drop').length) {
            $(data.element).clone().appendTo(t.closest('.drop'));
            // node data:
            // if(data.data.jstree && data.data.origin) { console.log(data.data.origin.get_node(data.element); }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the name of the dropped item in **$(data.event.target).text()**.

Comment: try **var dragText = $(data.event.target).text();** "dragtext" will give you the text in javascript

Comment: but i am getting all the previos dta droped as appended

Comment: Its var dragText = $(**data.element**).text(); for getting the currently draged and droped element alone.Hope it works.

Comment: thanks. you are awsome.add your mail id in your profile

Comment: is there any way to get the  name of parent node of dropped node?